Create 2D-Array with a user form TextBoxes
I would like to create an array from the userform input of the TextBoxes. However, I get an error message (Type mismatch (Error 13)) when I want to convert the values from the userform TextBox into the number type clng or cdate
My array looks like this:
mFields = Array( _

Array(CStr(TextBox1), 2, vbString, "R", 0), _
Array(CStr(TextBox2), 3, vbString, "R", 0), _
Array(CDate(TextBox3), 3, vbString, "R", 0), _
Array(CLng(TextBox4), 4, vbLong, "R", 100))


What is in TextBox3 and what is in TextBox4?

A 2D array whould have rows and columns... If you want/need an array of arrays, this is usually named as jagged array.  You should better explain (in words) what you really try doing.

Please don't add comments to clarify. Formatting is too limited. Put everything in one place, [edit] your question instead.

As I said in my above comment, a 2D array has rows and columns. It can be loaded being declared (As Variant or without specifying the type when Variant is default) without dimensions and being loaded with reference to a range. Or containing the dimensions from declaration, or (using ReDim to change the dimensions):
Sub test2DArrays()
 Dim arr2D
 arr2D = Range("A1:B10").Value
 Debug.Print UBound(arr2D), UBound(arr2D, 2) 'it returns 10 rows and 2 columns
 
 ReDim arr2D(3, 2) 'ReDim the array dimensions (before loading manually or by iteration)
 arr2D(1, 1) = "X"
 arr2D(1, 2) = "y"
 arr2D(2, 1) = 10
 arr2D(2, 2) = 20
 arr2D(3, 1) = Array(2, 3, 4)
 arr2D(3, 2) = Array("A", "B", 30, 40)
   'you can return (checking in immediate window) as
   Debug.Print arr2D(1, 1), arr2D(2, 2)       'it returns X   20
   Debug.Print arr2D(3, 1)(0), arr2D(3, 2)(1) 'it returns 2    B
 
 Erase arr2D 'clear the array
 ReDim arr2D(2, 3) 'two rows and three columns
 Dim i As Long, j As Long
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr2D)       'array number of rows
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr2D, 2) 'array number of columns
        arr2D(i, j) = i * j
    Next j
 Next i
 'returning some elements of the loaded array
 Debug.Print arr2D(1, 2), arr2D(2, 2), arr2D(2, 3) 'it returns 2  4  6

 ReDim Preserve arr2D(2, 5) 'it keeps existing loaded elements and extend (ONLY THE LAST DIMENSION) with two elements
 arr2D(1, 4) = "extended element on first row"
 arr2D(2, 4) = "extended element on the second row"
 
 Debug.Print arr2D(1, 4) 'returns "extended element on first row"...
End Sub


I write the userform objects in the array. I want to check whether the values from the user form are already in the table. The data is then entered into the table. This works perfectly for the string entries, but the data types for date or long do not work. I get the error message (Type mismatch (Error 13) The structure of the individual arrays : Each object in the userform has 5 associated parameters: - object name, - position/column in the table, - data type, - if it is "required" and - if the value (for numbers) should be negative, zero or positive.

@PIeter_105 I am afraid your question is not related to the array at all... Did you separately try something as Debug.print Day(CDate(TextBox3.text))? Does it return the correct day? The same for the other case Debug.print CLng(TextBox4.text). If you do not receive any error (which look improbable for me) it means that it needs to specify the Text property of the text box...

@FaneDuro:
I had already tried this with the Text property of the text box. But it doesn't work The error message Type mismatch (Error 13) appears for CLng or Cdate

@PIeter_105 Did you try my above suggestions, as they are, forgetting the array issue? If so, don't you receive any error? If  receiving, it would be good to mention it. If not any error, even it is hard to believe that, please state it. If you do not do exactly what I suggested, why not?
